# String substring index could be the length of string

Tags: java, string, substring

This is a Java string problem. I use the `substring(beginindex)` to obtain a substring.
Considering `String s="hello"`, the length of this string is 5. However when I use `s.substring(5)` or `s.substring(5,5)` the compiler **didn't give me an error.** The index of the string should be from 0 to length-1.
Why it doesn't apply to my case? I think that `s.substring(5)` should give me an error but it doesn't.

Comment: `s.substring(s.length())` is silly but valid

Comment: *"I think when I use s.substring(5), it should give me error while it didn't"* - Don't rely on your intuition.  Read the javadocs.  They say it shouldn't.

Answer (score 9):

Because the `endIndex` is exclusive, as specified in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex
>   is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is
>   larger than endIndex.

---

> I think when I use s.substring(5), it should give me error while it
>   didn't

Why would it be?

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the
>   end of this string.

Since the `beginIndex` is not larger than the `endIndex` (5 in your case), it's perfectly valid. You will just get an empty String.

If you look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java):

```
1915  public String substring(int beginIndex) {
1916      return substring(beginIndex, count);
1917  }
....
1941  public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
1942      if (beginIndex < 0) {
1943          throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
1944      }
1945      if (endIndex > count) {
1946          throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
1947      }
1948      if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
1949          throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex);
1950      }
1951      return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
1952          new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
1953  }
```

Thus `s.substring(5);` is equivalent to `s.substring(5, s.length());` which is `s.substring(5,5);` in your case.

When you're calling `s.substring(5,5);`, it returns an empty String since you're calling the constructor(which is private package) with a `count` value of 0 (`count` represents the number of characters in the String):

```
644 String(int offset, int count, char value[]) {
645         this.value = value;
646         this.offset = offset;
647         this.count = count;
648 }
```

Comment: but it didn't have the index ==5. but I can use s.substring(5)?why

Comment: @user3382017 `s.substring(5);` is equivalent to `s.substring(5, s.length());` which is `s.substring(5,5);` for "Hello".

Answer (score 6):

Because `substring` is defined as such, you can find it in [the Javadoc of `String.substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

> @exception  IndexOutOfBoundsException  if the beginIndex is negative,
>   or *endIndex is **larger than** the length of this String object*, or
>   beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

It's useful in many cases that you can always create a substring that starts *after* a character in a String.

Because `endIndex` can be the length of the string, and `beginIndex` can be as large as `endIndex` (but not larger), it is also okay for `beginIndex` to be equal to the length of the string.

Comment: +1. You just taught me something. minIndex can be equal to length. I never did it, so I assumed it was illegal.

Answer (score 1):

In first case (`s.substring(5)`), Oracle docs says

> ...
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if **beginIndex** is negative or larger than the length of this String object.
>   ...

In second case (`s.substring(5,5)`), it says that

> ...
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the **beginIndex** is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex
>   ...